# automate click submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to automate clicking the button "Leave the HTML5 Trial"  or "Join the HTML5 Trial" on this webpage when I open it using a specific web browser

```
http://www.youtube.com/html5
```

my initial idea is to embed the webpage into a new HTML page and use javascript to click the button when the page is loaded, but it seems it can't be embeded

any other ideas? thanKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very bad if JavaScript allowed you to do this. Consider the security implications. For example, if a malicious site embedded a Facebook iframe and then simulated you clicking somewhere in that iframe, it could force you to unwillingly take an action you had no awareness of.

You cannot do this.

**Update:**

You say you need to script some operations. If you're leaving/joining the HTML 5 trial for a specific user for which you know the YouTube login credentials, what you could try is scripting this server-side. This may be a little tricky, but you could use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to capture what the HTTP requests look like when you manually log in and click the button, then mimic these same actions in your script (using curl or wget or whatever is available in your environment).

Comment: This answer is assuming you're wanting to have your third-party site join/leave the trial using a YouTube iframe. My apologies if that's not what you meant.

Comment: ok, are there any other ideas? I'm doing some research work, which requires me to scripting some operations, one of the operation is to join and leave html5 trial

Comment: See my update. If you're just scripting operations for a certain user, not other users, you may be able to do this outside of JavaScript.